# Is this variadic template argument deduction correct?

Tags: templates, reference, c++11, forwarding, variadic

I've been experimenting with variadic templates and argument forwarding. I think I've found some inconsistent behaviour.

To illustrate, this program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <tuple>
#include <cxxabi.h>

template <typename... Args> struct X {};

struct A {
    A () {}
    A (const A &) {
        std :: cout << "copy\n";
    }
};

template <typename T> const char * type_name () {
    return abi :: __cxa_demangle (typeid (T) .name (), 0, 0, NULL);
}

void foo () {}

template <typename... Args>
void foo (const A &, Args ... args) {
    std :: cout << type_name <X <Args...>> () << "\n“;    foo (args...);
}

int main () {
    foo (A(), A());
}
```

Outputs the following:

```
X<A, A>
copy
X<A>
```

Even though the template specialisation of foo has a const reference first argument, the variadic arguments are passed by value because the template types are deduced as non-reference types, as the `X<A>` output indicates.

So, I consult [Thomas Becker](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html):

> ```
> template<typename T>
> void foo(T&&);
> ```
>
> Here, the following apply:
>
> 1. When foo is called on an lvalue of type A, then T resolves to A& and
>      hence, by the reference collapsing
>      rules above, the argument type
>      effectively becomes A&.
> 2. When foo is called on an rvalue of type A, then T resolves to A, and
>      hence the argument type becomes A&&.

And try this:

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo (const A &, Args && ... args) {
    std :: cout << type_name<X<Args...>>() << "\n";
    foo (args...);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
X<A, A>
X<A&>
```

Now I'm stumped. There are three invocations of foo here. In my head, `main()` should deduce `foo<A,A,A>(A&&,A&&,A&&)` (because A() is an unnamed rvalue, hence a reference) which overload-resolves to `foo<A,A,A>(const A&,A&&,A&&)`. This in turn deduces `foo<A,A>(A&&,A&&)` and so on.

Question is: how come `X<A,A>` has non-reference `A`s but `X<A&>` has a reference `A`?

This causes a problem because I can't use `std::forward` in the recursion.

Comment: Are you sure your code corresponds to your output? I get `X<A> X<>`, or increasing number of `A()`s in `main`, `X<A, A> copy X<A> X<>`. It is a mystery how could you get `X<A&>` as the last line at all, with or without ampersand. It should be `X<>` regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I assume you pasted the wrong main and the correct one is :

```
 int main () {
        foo (A(), A(), A());
 }
```

I hope I guessed right, otherwise the rest of this post is invalid :)
Second, I'm not really good with standard terminology, so I hope the following is not too imprecise.

I often feel that the simplest way to understand what happen with variadic template is just to generate yourself what the compiler will effectively do.

For example your first try

`void foo (const A &, Args ... args)`

will actually be unpack by the compiler to something like those 3 functions :

`void foo3 (const A & a, A a1, A a2)`
`void foo2 (const A & a, A a0)`
`void foo1 (const A & a)`

When calling `foo3(A(), A(), A());` in the main the compiler will do an optimization and just default-construct a1 and a2 instead of default-construct and copy. However when calling foo2 inside foo3 the compiler cannot optimize anymore hence when calling `foo2(a1, a2`) the parameter a0 inside foo2 must be copy-constructed. And it's the copy-construction of a0 that we can see in the traces ("copy")

By the way, I don't understand why you pass the first element by const ref but the rest by value. Why not pass everything by const-ref ?

`void foo (const A &, const Args& ... args)`

OK, now about your second try with rvalue-ref :

`void foo (const A &, Args && ... args)`

When calling `foo3(A(), A(), A());` in the main, `A()` is an rvalue so this rule applies :

> When foo is called on an rvalue of
>   type A, then T resolves to A, and
>   hence the argument type becomes A&&.

So foo3 looks like this:

```
void foo3 (const A &, A && a1, A && a2) {
    std :: cout << type_name<X<A, A>>() << "\n";
    foo2 (a1, a2);
}
```

But be careful here. a1 and a2 are NOT rvalue anymore. They have a name hence they are lvalue.

So now inside foo2, this rule applies :

> When foo is called on an lvalue of
>   type A, then T resolves to A& and
>   hence, by the reference collapsing
>   rules above, the argument type
>   effectively becomes A&.

So a0 type inside foo2 will effectively be A& and that's why we can see `X<A&>` in the traces.

To use perfect forwarding I think you need to give-up this weird assumption :

> This causes a problem because I can't
>   use std::forward in the recursion.

I don't understand why. The following code should be correct :

```
void foo(A&&, Args&&... args)
{
   std::cout << type-name<X<Args...>> () << "\n";
   foo(std::forward<Args>(args...));
}
```

When calling foo() for the recursion , std::forward will turns each args... from lvalue to rvalue again and so the deduction will be correct.